# Warnings when using minifyenabled: true

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to enable minifyEnabled in android build gradle. But building fails with the following error.

```
Error:org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Warnings found during shrinking, please use -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings to suppress them.
```

So why I'm getting this and to fix this issue where should I add -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings

Gradle Code

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true


        }

    }
```

Proguard (I have not modified proguard)

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

Thank you!

Comment: proguard is all you need

Comment: I have added proguard on release build type. But when I add it in debug I get Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'.
> Job failed, see logs for details error

Comment: set minifyEnable false in debug or apply the same proguard..

Comment: @AdeelTurk After cleaning project the proguard error got fixed but still getting minify waring. Can you tell me where to add -dontwarn or -ignorewarnings

Comment: please post your proguard file

Comment: @AdeelTurk I have not modified anything in proguard . It has -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
# rename the source files to something meaningless, but it must be retained
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

Comment: Wait it looks weird. Adding it in question

Comment: edit your question and add your pro guard there..

Comment: ok juts add -ignorewarnings this on the top of these lines you mentioned above in pro guard.. and set minifyEnabled false in debug